# Detecting an embed title in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('kuba144i'))
message.channel.send("Key Word Detected ");
else

```
for(var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
    if(message.embeds[i].title.includes("kuba144i") || message.embeds[i].title.includes("kuba144i")) {
        message.channel.send("Detected");
        break; 
    }
}
```

After sending an embed the bot crashes and this error displays in console: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null"
can somebody help me with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your for loop to this:

```
message.embeds.some((item) => {
    if(item.title.includes("kuba144i") || item.title.includes("kuba144i")) {
    message.channel.send("Detected");
    return false; 
}
return true
})
```